# Общий класс для активити

Tags: java, android

Допустим есть стандартный класс:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }
 }
```

Как создать общий класс для активити(Допустим, `XMLtemplate.java`), чтобы в зависимости от параметра загружалась определенная активити в `setContentView`.
Например, при создании экземпляра класса `XMLtemplate` передать некий параметр, указывающий на определенную активити(При параметре `main` загружать `R.layout.activity_main`, при `about` -> `R.layout.activity_about`):

```
 XMLtemplate xmltemplate = new XMLtemplate();
 xmltemplate.param("main");
```

Чтобы не создавать каждый раз класс `MainActivity` или `AboutActivity` и не прописывать в методе `onCreate` стандартный код.

Comment: А каким образом вы собираетесь разруливать обработку данных внутри активити? Ведь я так понимаю R.layout.activity_main и R.layout.activity_about имеют разные компоненты? И вы в одной активити хотите написать код для обработки всех случаев разметки?

Comment: @Werder, у меня не особо много данных. В каждой активити текст и только, а через параметр я буду указывать, какой показывать и загружать - по типу страниц в учебнике

Comment: Имеет ли смысл тогда делать разные активити? Может стоит просто в интенте передавать нужный для отображения текст? Это упроситит реализацию и количество кода

Comment: @Werder, можно пример?

Answer (score 2):

- Создайте один активити, например `MainActivity`, с одной разметкой.
- Далее при вызове этого активити в `Intent` передавайте нужный вам для отображения текст следующим образом:

  `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   intent.putString("key", "some useful text");
   startActivity(intent);`
- В самой `MainActivity` вытаскивайте этот текст следующим образом, и делайте с ним что нужно:

  `String text = getIntent().getString("key");`